# Which one is more accurate?

Tags: prepositions, difference

In this situation:

> She doesn't take after her sister at all! Her treatment is totally different **to** her sister.

vs:

> She doesn't take after her sister at all! Her treatment is totally different **from** her sister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Different* is [most often](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043846/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/different-from-than-or-to) used with *from*, so

> She doesn't take after her sister at all! Her treatment is totally different from her sister.

would be the natural option for most people.

Answer (score 1):

*Different **to*** is pretty rare<sup>†</sup>, and it expresses no distinct nuance; there is no reason why you should ever use anything except *different **from***.

However, you should take care in any comparison to make sure that you are comparing things which are actually comparable. Of course "her treatment" is different from "her sister"—one is an action, the other is a person! What you probably mean is

> Her treatment is totally different from her sister***'s*** — *tthat is, her sister's treament*.

Note, moreover, that *take after* is ordinarily used to express inheritable similarities, most often similarities of physical appearance but sometimes of behaviors and attitudes. If what you mean by "her treatment" is the way she treats somebody or something, you need to specify that (*her treatment of Joe*); if what you mean is the treatment she is receiving, *take after* doesn't come into play at all.

---

<sup>†</sup> Google Ngrams suggests that *to* is somewhat more common in BrE than AmE, but has never risen to 10% of the frequency of *from* even in BrE.

Comment: Thanks @StoneyB  So "different to" is more common in British English than in American English!

Comment: @Amin Yes; but it is UNcommon in both.